# User Control ViewState/State Help needed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, asp-usercontrols

I need help making this code work better. Currently, what happens is when it reloads, I loose the third value which is a calculated value . I would like for my page to reload without loosing the values for each property and each instance of the user control on the page.

Thanks in advance

```
  Private _Length As Double = 0.0
        Public Property Length() As Double
            Get
                If (Me.ViewState("calcLength") IsNot Nothing) Then
                    Return CType(ViewState("calcLength"), Double)
                End If
                Return _Length

            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                ViewState("calcLength") = value
                txtLength.Text = value.ToString()
                _Length = value
            End Set
        End Property


     Private _Width As Double = 0.0
        Public Property Width() As Double
            Get
                If (Me.ViewState("calcwidth") IsNot Nothing) Then
                    Return CType(Me.ViewState("calcwidth"), Double)
                End If
                Return _Width
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                Me.ViewState("calcwidth") = value
                Me.txtwidth.Text = value.ToString()
                _Width = value
            End Set
        End Property


     Private _calculatedboardfeet As Double = 0.0
        Public Property CalculateBoardFeet() As Double
            Get
                If (Me.ViewState("calculateboardfeet") IsNot Nothing) Then
                    _calculatedboardfeet = CType(ViewState("calculateboardfeet"), Double)

                End If
                Return _calculatedboardfeet
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                Me.ViewState("calculateboardfeet") = value
                Me.lblCalculatedValue.Text = String.Format("{0:f2}", value)
                _calculatedboardfeet = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I needed was to call the assignment part of my code in the pre_Render event in the Usercontrol. It comes later than the Parent Page's PageLoad() event, which is when the information needed will be available in the control's viewstate

Answer (score 2):

There's this portion which I 'think' doesn't make sense, though it may not be the cause of the problem. I've yet to studied the rest of the codes in detail.

```
ElseIf (Me.ViewState("txtwidth") Is Nothing) Then
      Return CType(Me.ViewState("txtwidth"), Double)
```

If the `ViewState` item cannot be found (i.e. `Is Nothing`), how do you return the cast-ed value? This is the same for the 3 properties.

Comment: I apologize for that, I had some old edits in the old code I posted. I have made modifications to it. The problem still persists. Not sure what I can do to make sure that whenever the usercontrol reloads, the calculated value is recalculated or reloaded from viewstate as it should for that particular control.

Comment: Well, when do you retrieve the values? If you retrieve it too early in the page's life-cycle, viewstate values might not be available.

Comment: The values are being retrieved after the control's page load is fired.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the "third value which is the calculated value"?  Third as in CalculateBoardFeet()?

At what stage in the page life cycle are you calling these properties?

Why are you storing the values both in ViewState and in the control's .Text property, and then again in a class variable?  Too. Many. Copies.

If you programmatically set the control's .Text property, that value should be restored on postback for you, without you having to explicitly set ViewState yourself.

Comment: the values are being retrieved after page load. I have all three options available in case but still non seems to be doing the trick for the calculatedboardfeet property.